# Programatically specifying the GraphQL schema in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm using a 'code first' approach for defining the schema using [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/Enigmatis/graphql-java-annotations) instead of defining the schema in a separate `.graphqls` file.

I'm trying to specify the schema by using `GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer` as mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#execution-graphqlsource) but I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.graphql.execution.MissingSchemaException: No GraphQL schema definition was configured.
> at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
> at app//org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultGraphQlSourceBuilder.build(DefaultGraphQlSourceBuilder.java:136)
> at app//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlAutoConfiguration.graphQlSource(GraphQlAutoConfiguration.java:90)

Here's my configuration class. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```java
@Configuration
public class GraphQLConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer sourceBuilderCustomizer() {
        GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = AnnotationsSchemaCreator.newAnnotationsSchema()
                .query(GraphQLQuery.class)
                .build();

        return graphQlSourceBuilder -> graphQlSourceBuilder.configureGraphQl(graphQLBuilder -> graphQLBuilder.schema(graphQLSchema));
    }
}
```